# How to send information from android app to SOTI MobiControl?

Tags: android, mdm, soti

I have a setup with an android device managed by the MDM Soti / MobiControl.
I want to use a script to roll out an app update.

This are the steps:

---

1. MDM calls App with

   ```
   sendintent -b "intent:#Intent;action=com.myapp.syncdata;end“
   ```
2. App does a sync with the Webservice
3. App notifies MDM that it finished syncing
4. MDM uninstalls the old App
5. MDM installs the new App

---

With the soti script command in #1 and a BroadcastReceiver in my Android App I can already trigger sync events. 
But I wonder how can I inform the MDM that the synchronisation is finished?
How can I do step 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What we finally did is this:**

1. MDM calls App with

   ```
   sendintent -b "intent:#Intent;action=com.myapp.syncdata;end“
   ```
2. App does a sync with the Webservice.
3. App writes an *upload.ini* file to the sdcard with this content:

   ```
   [upload]
   upload=1
   ```
4. In MobiControl we added a [custom data](http://www.soti.net/mc/help/v12/en/default.htm#Web/Devices/Plus/Custom-Data.htm?Highlight=custom%20data) field, monitoring the existence and value of `upload=1` inside the *upload.ini*. All devices with `upload=1` are moved into a virtual group.

5.+6. On all devices in the virtual group we start a update-script wich uninstalls the old App, installs the new App and deletes the *upload.ini*

**Thanks again to the SOTI support for their help!**

**NOTE:** This only works on "Android+" devices. Android+ means SOTI has a special cooperation with the manufacturers, like with Samsung.